# How to parse string?

Tags: c#, sql, json, parsing

I have a chat application where user can enter any string in textbox like - json string, XML string or normal string/text. I am storing this string/data into database.

Now I have to show that data (chat details) in a JSON format. But my problem is as user can enter any data/string in chat application so if user enter's any JSON string in invalid JSON format then my final output/result (which is in JSON format) is not generated due to this.

Can anyone help me out to resolve this ?

I am working on C#, SQL Server and JQuery.

My final output will be like this:

```
"[
    {"Key":"A", "Value":"xyz"},
    {"Key":"B", "Value":"6"},
    {"Key":"C", "Value":"{"Email":"abc@gmail.com", "Address":"Park ROad"}"}
]"
```

There is a problem in third row (where Key is "C"). Means user has entered the JSON string and that may be valid or invalid.

Comment: Add a validation so the user can't send invalid JSON data

Comment: Either that, or escape the data and make sure it is just *a string* and not interpreted anyhow.

Comment: The problem here is string concatenation. If you had stored the string, containing json, inside an object and then serialized that object to string, it would not create invalid json data, but escape all the quotes.

Comment: Allowing users entering a json string in GUI is wrong by definition.

Comment: Show how you get this JSON. Inner JSON should have become escaped when serialized.

Comment: #Kai, can you please suggest how we can escape this ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a Dynamic object in this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3806407/3241790) you will fine good explained. How to use it.